# Mahout : user that bought XX also bought XX

Tags: autosuggest, mahout

I found similar questions but the answer didn't satisfy me. Essentially I would like to implement in mahout an item suggester based on purchases (or even ratings).
In mahout it seems that you have a user item model and the reccomendation is about user. Now I understand that we can replace the term user with item and having an item - item reccomendation but I think it would not work as expected. For instance if we have this data:

```
User Item
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    3
3    1
```

and if I am on item 1 page and I ask for a reccomendation, I am expecting item 3 as result because it is chosen more than item 2. I don't understand if this is easily configurable in mahout and how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a case of recommending items to items, no.

Do you mean that, on an item's page, for example, you want to show items that were most frequently bought? This is actually simpler than a recommender problem in that the answer is not personalized; it does not depend on the user. That's good.

You still need user data though of course. In the non-distributed Mahout framework, you can most easily accomplish this with one of the "boolean pref" `DataModel`s, `GenericItemBasedBooleanPrefDataModel`, and an appropriate `ItemSimilarity` metric like `LogLikelihoodSimilarity`. Just call `Recommender.mostSimilarItems()`.

It's actually answering more intelligently than just telling you what was bought most frequently with that item -- that would tend to favor items that are merely frequently bought, full stop. This metric will extract those that are unusually frequently bought given their overall popularity.

Comment: can it run realtime with relatively small power and ram? Items are in categories and I want just the ones in the same category

Comment: It depends on how big your data, and how small your resources, but sure, yes.

Comment: but sorry if I ask you this, my datamodel is on mongoDb so I am wondering if I have to build everytime a memory GenericItemBasedBooleanPrefDataModel and run the reccomender on it (when the page is rendered) or should I just record the model changes (like new purchases)? If I create a MongoDbDataModel, then it will be updated everytime with not too much power right? (I am quite confused about mahout)

Comment: I would read all your data into memory periodically and build a model out of it. I would not try to access the Mongo instance in real time. If you do this it should be fast and simple.

Comment: But is it possible to create a model in memory from mongodb instance and then keep the memory model and mongodb updated?